# Conditionally Load JS for Block Style

Tags: block-editor

I've created a custom Gutenberg block for displaying posts in a scrolling timeline style, actually a Slick Slider. This all works great but it was built before the Query block came about and so now I'm investigating whether this would be better as an extension of that core block.

First off I simply added a custom block **style** with `register_block_style()`. I'm very happy with how this works, to a point: the styles load on the back and front end but for this to resemble the font end output it also needs to enqueue a JS file and the Slick script as a dependancy. This block is only currently used once, on the front page so I'd rather not load Slick all over the site. I know that I can enqueue it conditionally using `has_block()` but (as I understand it) I can only use that to test for a Query block, not my specific style.

None of this was an issue using `register_block_type()` since I could define `viewScript` and `editorScript` but I'm struggling to figure out the most efficient/correct way to achieve the same conditionality for a block **style**.

Can I achieve anything close to `viewScript` and `editorScript` in conjunction with `register_block_style()`? Should I instead be using a block **variation** or even a block **pattern**?

Comment: blocks styles are purely CSS, they don't include JS as they're just a style of the same block, the goal is to make the block visually/aesthetically different, not functionally different, as strictly the only difference between the block and its styled version is a HTML class. What you're describing sounds more like a block variant or a totally separate block

Comment: Thanks, @Tom J Nowell. That makes sense. My workaround in the editor is to display my slider as a horizontally scrolling, overflowing CSS grid so it looks aesthetically close, just without the JS. I still need to address conditionally enqueuing my scripts on the front though.